# Magento product attribute value returns "No"

Tags: php, magento, product

Im trying to get all attributes and values for all my products, im doing this for every product:

```
foreach($product->getAttributes() as $attribute)
{
    $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
    $fieldVal = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
}
```

For most products it works, but for the products, that are simples and have no configs, the values for some attributs return "No" instead of their real value.